# Punishment for faker/cheater husband in Islam

Tags: fiqh, husband-wife, punishment

If a man, who is married from 19 years and he has 5 children but still he cheats his wife. Once he wants to marry a woman without the permission of first wife. He continuously cheats his wife from previous 10 years. Then he leave that woman because his wife caught them but from sometime He again make a relation with some another woman and again cheats his wife. He beats her and not fulfilled her demands but he gives time, money, love , care etc for another woman instead to give this all to his wife. His wife caught him again but he still do same work.He also have sexual relationship with that woman which is non-mehram to him. In this condition, What is a punishment in Islam for this type of man who continuously cheats his wife ? What Wife should do in this condition?

Comment: are you asking what punishmet the wife can give or what punishment the state can give?

Comment: Do you have four witnesses who caught him in the act or are these only baseless accusations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A married man if commits sexual intercourse with some other woman Islamic punishment for him is stone to death.
You should approad court to get him punished as per law.

Comment: If she followed your advice she would be punished for false accusation as long as she don't come up with four witnesses who caught him in the act or made a vow.